# MySQL init file to update innodb auto_increment

Tags: mysql, innodb, auto-increment

I am trying to execute a small statement each time mysql service restarts. I have he following code in a file declared in my.ini (init-file option):

```
ALTER  TABLE skydb.w_messaging_type_b_files_processing_queue AUTO_INCREMENT = 
SELECT  GREATEST( IFNULL(
                      ( SELECT  MAX(ID)
                            FROM  skydb.w_messaging_type_b_files_processing_queue),0),
                IFNULL(
                      ( SELECT  MAX(ID)
                            FROM  skydb.w_messaging_type_b_files_unparsed),0
                      ), IFNULL(
                      ( SELECT  MAX(ID)
                            FROM  skydb.w_messaging_type_b_files),0)
                )+1
```

The log says:

```
2016-02-13T23:19:14.135305Z 1 [ERROR] 1064
    You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
    MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
    near 'SELECT GREATEST( IFNULL((SELECT MAX(ID) FROM skydb.w_messaging_type_b_files_proc' at line 1
```

As you may guess my db uses innodb storage engine, and i want to avoid having auto increment reset on table processing queue...

Any ideas what i am doing wrong?

Comment: Only a 'constant' can be used there.  What were you hoping to achieve with the `ALTER`?

Comment: Hi Rick. I am trying to update the auto_increment value of table w_messaging_type_b_files_processing_queue.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "w_messaging_type_b_files_processing_queue".

Comment: If you need a single auto-inc across multiple tables, do not do it this way; instead have a single table providing the auto-inc values.

Comment: Rick w_messaging_type_b_files_processing_queue is the name of the table.